# It is possible to pass 2 differents types of parameters to a Laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, routes

I already have a GET route with an URI `/projects/{id}` which displays Infos of a project with a given id. I also have a GET index route (`/projects`), which shows all my projects.

My problem is that I currently try to create different indexes (for example one which only displays the projects where I am assigned [e.g. on `/projects/mines`], or the projects which are pending administrator approval [e.g. on `/projects/proposals`], and still others displays).

So I want to know if I can have two GET routes `/projects/{id}`and `/projects/{display_mode}` which will be calling two differents methods of my `ProjectController` (respectively `show` and `index`).

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have one route `/projects` which returns all projects as default.
If there is query parameter like

```
/projects?displayMode=proposals
```

then you can apply filters.

In your controller it would look something like this

```
$projects = Project::query();
if ($request->query('displayMode') == 'proposals')
    $projects->where('pending', true)

return $projects->get();
```

You can add multiple filters too in the same way

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about specific Laravel options for the route definitions (sorry!), but if the `{id}` will always be an integer and `{display_mode}` will always have non-digits in it, you could keep just one route, but do the conditional handling in your controller.  Just have the mainAction do something like…

```
return preg_match('/^\d+$/', $param) ? idHelperAction($param) : displayModeHelperAction($param);
```

Then create those two helper functions and have them return whatever you want.

`$param` is supposed to be whatever you get from that route parameter -- `/projects/{param}`.

That should call the idHelperAction for routes where `$param` is all digits and nothing else; otherwise, it should call the displayModeHelperAction.  Either way, it sends the same `$param` to the helper function and returns whatever that helper function returns -- effectively splitting one route definition into two possible actions.

Of course, you might have to add some context in the code sample.  If the functions are all defined in the same class, you might need to use `$this->idHelperAction($param)` or `self::idHelperAction($param)` (and the same with the other helper action), depending on whether it's static or not; or tell it where to find the functions if you put them in another class, etc., etc. -- all the normal contextual requirements.